# Importing Modules twice in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is more of a general question / best practice I wanted advice on.

I am creating a handler for SSH connections using paramiko and in my **enter** i have a try / except in the case I cannot create the ssh tunnel. I wanted to shorten the exception line from this:

```
     try:
        # Attempts to establish a connection to the specified host
        self._ssh.connect(self.hostname, username=self.username, password=self.password, timeout=30)
        return self._ssh
    except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException, paramiko.SSHException, socket_error) as e:
        # Message and Error logged if we have a failed connection to the specified host
        logger.error(f'Message=Failed to connect to {self.hostname}, Error={e}')
```

to

```
     try:
        # Attempts to establish a connection to the specified host
        self._ssh.connect(self.hostname, username=self.username, password=self.password, timeout=30)
        return self._ssh
    except (BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException, socket_error) as e:
        # Message and Error logged if we have a failed connection to the specified host
        logger.error(f'Message=Failed to connect to {self.hostname}, Error={e}')
```

In order to do this, I imported paramiko twice as such

```
import paramiko
from socket import error as socket_error
from paramiko import BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException
```

I feel like this is bad since I am technically importing two instances of this, but I wanted advise if I just suck it up and make the line longer and add breaks where needed, or if this kind of behavior is acceptable in most dev environments.

Any references or reading available would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: I personally think this is fine.  If it makes you uncomfortable, one compromise is e.g. `import paramiko as pmk`.

Comment: I agree, I actually decided to go this route the more I think about it

from paramiko import SSHClient, BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException

This way I am only importing what I need now. If i need something in the future i can just add to it as necessary (to a degree of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, when you import a module, python first looks at the `sys.modules` to see if it is already there or not. If it was, python will reference it to your `global` namespace(**That's it, there is no second instance**). If it wasn't there, then python loads and runs it into memory and again give a reference to the global namespace. look at this :

```
#file2.py

print('module file2.py imported')
```

now in main.py:

```
import sys


print('file2' in sys.modules)  # It is False.

import file2                   # loads and runs then give reference to global

print('file2' in sys.modules)  # It is True

import file2                   # It is already in sys.modules, just give reference.
```

You should't see `'module file2.py imported'` twice in the output.

In addition, both `from module import something` and `import module` are doing the same thing, I mean in both situation, the `module` will loaded into memory and added into `sys.modules`, the only difference is that, in the first one, `module` is in your global, but inthe second one `something` is in your global as a label. I think it's now depends on how you prefer. Long and explicit way or `from paraniko import *`